# SQL - How to select rows with the same ID values where all other column values are also identical

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I cannot find the answer to the abovementioned problem in the title.

I need to select all rows that have the **identical ID** and **all other column values must also be identical** as well. This table consists of 20 columns.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
select id, name, ...other fields
from my_table
where id in (
    Select id, count(id)
    from my_table
    group by id, name, ...other fields
    having count(id) > 1
)
```

Change group by and where conditions accordingly